# Passing information on from a html form to java server

Tags: java, html

Im trying to create a program that when the user puts in the address in the browser the server outputs the website and asks the user for a username and password and if the information enter is correct a new line is printed and if not another website is presented. what i am having trouble with is passing the information on to the server once the user presses the submit button. here is what i have written so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Login {

    public static void printPage(BufferedWriter writer, BufferedReader rd) {
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(writer);

        pr.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        pr.println("Connection: close");
        pr.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        pr.println();
        pr.println("<html>");
        pr.println("<body>");
        pr.println("<pre>" + "<h1>" + "Enter Your Username and Password: " + "</h1>" + "</pre>");
        pr.println("<form action = \"matthew.local:1050\" method=get>");
        pr.println("<pre>User Name:  <input name = login><br>");
        pr.println("Password:    <input type = password name = password></pre>");
        pr.println("<p><input type = submit value = submit></p>");
        pr.println("</form>");
        pr.println("</body>");
        pr.println("</html>");
        pr.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            ServerSocket listen = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Accepting Connections on port: " + port);
            while (true) {
                Socket sock = listen.accept();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
                String line = rd.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    sock.close();
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
                do {
                    line = rd.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(line);
                } while (line.length() > 0);
                printPage(wr, rd);

                rd.close();
                wr.close();
                sock.close();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is this homework?  it's certainly a difficult way to set up a web site!

Comment: Change matthew.local:1050 to localhost:1050 and try

Comment: yeah its for homework. i realized that i need to pass the form onto a cgi script. what I'm confused about now is how to do that and what to name the cgi file. like do i name the java file .cgi?